# Explanation of a proof from Stacks Project: Noetherian ring of formal powers series

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, formal-power-series

I'm trying to understand the [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0306) proof of the generalization of Hilbert's basis theorem to formal power series. Please, don't mark this as a duplicate since I don't ask for a general proof of this fact, but rather want to explain a step in a specific proof to me. For convenience, I also add a screenshot to this post.

[image]

I don't understand the last part of the proof after the "so on". Suppose that we know that, for each $n \geq 0$, there are $c_{1,n},...,c_{n_{d_0},n} \in R$ such that
$$f - \sum c_{d,i}f_{d,i} - \sum c_{i,1}xf_{d_0,i} - ... - \sum c_{i,n}x^nf_{d_0,i} \in (x^{d_0 + n + 1})\cap I.$$

How this implies that

$f = \sum c_{d,i}f_{d,i} + \sum_i(\sum_e c_{i,e}x^e) f_{d_0,i}$? We can't sum infinitely many factors in a ring, even if it is a ring of power series.

Comment: What does $h.o.t.$ mean in the definition of $I_d?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It means that $ax^d + a_1x^{d+1} + a_2x^{d+2} + ... \in I$.

Comment: Oh, okay, “higher other terms.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $a \in I_d$ if $a$ is a leading coefficient of some $f \in I$ of order $d$.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm having the same issue with all the proofs I've seen. There are answers to similar questions on this site, but no one seems to be taking issue with the fact that the sum is infinite.

Answer (score 4):

You can define convergence in the ring of formal power series $R[[x]]$.  The sequence of ideals $J_n:=(x^n)$, $n\geq 0$, defines a neighborhood of $0$.  The function $v(f) = \max\{n : f\in J_n\}$ (and $v(0)=\infty$) defines a metric $d(f,g)=2^{-v(f-g)}$.  Hence the infinite sums are well-defined (they converge in the above sense).

---

In the sum
$$
f = \sum c_{d,i}f_{d,i} + \sum_i(\sum_e c_{i,e}x^e) f_{d_0,i}
$$
the only "infinite" parts are the power series $\sum_ec_{i,e}x^e$; the sums over $i,d$ are finite, and $f\in I'$.

Comment: Sure, it's defined, but why should it be expressible as a *finite* linear combination of the (finitely many) $f_{d, j}$s, in accordance with the definition of "finitely generated"?

Comment: Ah, yes, I realized that shortly after I asked.